# Measure effect (Quantify) of each predictor feature importance from random forest regressor on the target value (lift or drop in number on target)

Tags: data-science, random-forest

How do I measure the lift or drop on my target values if I have the importance results from my random forest regressor model. Basically derving how to quantify the feature importance to change in our target.

For Example, I am predicting Sales values based on Feature1, Feature2 and Feature3 using Random Forest Regressor. I have the results from the model in terms of accuracy(MAPE) and individual feature importance of Feature1, Feature2 and Feature3.

How to know from the importance that increasing the Feature1 by 10 units would result in x units increase/decrease in my sales.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you have your models ready. Then you could use it to predict. As and input you could introduce whatever thing you would like to evaluate.
2. Perhaps you would like to have a look to other works going in a similar direction. Which I believe could be interpretation of the model. This is one that is also implemented in python: https://github.com/slundberg/shap